# Возможность выбрать несколько значений в input Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Осознаю глупость вопроса, но без вашей помощи не справляюсь. Есть код, который принимает только одно значение в `input`, мне же нужна возможность выбора нескольких значений через `"-"` или через `","`

```
print('Choose a group to scrape members from:')
i=0
for g in groups:
    print(str(i) + '- ' + g.title)
    i+=1
g_index = input("Enter a Number: ")
target_group=groups[int(g_index)]

print('Fetching Members...')
all_participants = []
all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)
```

Comment: См. [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: а где `input` ?

Comment: @n1tr0xs  это g_index, оттуда берется индекс группы

Answer (score 2):

Простой пример передачи нескольких значений:

```py
a = input("Введите данные через '-': ")
s = a.split("-") # Разбиваем строку по -
print(s) # Список из указанных значений
```

Далее из список обрабатываете как Вам требуется